# I am unable to resolve this error [android]

Tags: android, database, android-fragments, adapter

Hey guys please help me resolving this error i am attaching the ss below

[image: logcat 1]

[image: logcat 2]

[image: logcat 3]

Comment: have you implemented the gradle dependencies to create the schema? Like `implementation "android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:1.1.1"
    annotationProcessor "android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:1.1.1"`

Comment: Please share your restaurant DB class.

Comment: package com.nikhil.myproject.database

import androidx.room.ColumnInfo
import androidx.room.Entity
import androidx.room.PrimaryKey

@Entity(tableName = "restaurants")
data class RestaurantEntities(
    @PrimaryKey val id: Int,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "name") val name: String,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "rating") val rating: String,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "cost_for_one") val costForOne: String,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "image_url") val imageUrl: String
)

Comment: Here is my retaurant DB class